# c# encrypt SqlConnectionString in config

Tags: c#, encryption, config, sqlconnection

I was here making an sql connection in a class library and I was wondering how can I encrypt/decrypt an SqlConnectionString (or other things, if need be) in a config file (whether it's config from desktop, mobile or web)?

I already have functions to encrypt/decrypt strings. But I want to have it encrypted even when outside the program, so even if someone gets to the config file he won't know what the string is.

Must I do it "manually" (encrypt it in a program and copy/paste it to the config file) or is there another way to do it?

EDIT: I just read that it'd be best if the connection string was on the internet, in an API, only. Is it true? If it's true it'd be perfect because, I'm making an app/desktop/website that all connect to the same database, which is on a server. So, all of them have to connect to the internet anyway.

Comment: and in case you don't have an internet connection or server is down or whatever, users can not use application because connection string is on a internet?

Comment: Even if it was on the config file, the database is not local. It's on a server as well. So, it's useless to have one thing without the other anyway.

Comment: For web applications you can do the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986855.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am looking more for a way solve this issue for all platforms at once, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypt the connection string (or any other sensitive information) using an algorithm that the app, sitting on the user's PC, can decrypt, then anyone who gets to the config file AND the app executable can decipher how it is encrypted and get to the original connection string.

For the web app, this shouldn't be an issue (assuming you secure your server so that unauthorized people cannot access it), for the desktop app, it will be.

You could put some kind of gateway in front of the cloud database such that the desktop user would have to authenticate to obtain the connection string. That, or abstract the database access by building a web API, which you can secure by OAuth or something similar, and have the desktop user authenticate before using the app. Given that the database is on the internet, that's what I would do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Well, I can't exactly do anything in the server as it's a free somee server. (this is for the final project of a course I'm attending) Given that premise, can I do anything else? I am looking for a way solve this issue for all platforms at once, without needing to worry about it.

Comment: You could spin up a separate server with just this API gateway, where you'd keep the database credentials and only connect to the database from there. Granted, it's extra work. If this is a school assignment, could you live with not worrying about this at all? I mean, for a real-life project, I'd so something along the lines of what I've recommended; for a course-work, perhaps not doing anything would also do.

Comment: I think, at least for now, I won't worry about that anymore. I guess I'll probably use MD5 encryption to leave it encrypted by default and, only decrypt it when I need it.

Maybe I'll look further into it later. Thanks for the help, anyway. :)